# Dealing with Arrays in Flask-SqlAlchemy and MySQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a datamodel where I store a list of values separated by comma (1,2,3,4,5...).

In my code, in order to work with `arrays` instead of `string`, I have defined the model like this one:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    pk = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    __fake_array = db.Column(db.String(500), name="fake_array")

    @property
    def fake_array(self):
        if not self.__fake_array:
            return

        return self.__fake_array.split(',')

    @fake_array.setter
    def fake_array(self, value):
        if value:
           self.__fake_array = ",".join(value)
        else:
           self.__fake_array = None
```

This works perfect and from the point of view of my source code ***"fake_array"*** is an array, It's only transformed into `string` when it's stored in database.

The problem appears when I try to filter by that field. Expressions like  this doesn't work:

```
MyModel.query.filter_by(fake_array="1").all()
```

It seems that I cant filter using the *`SqlAlchemy` query model*.

What can I do here? Is there any way to filter this kind of fields?  Is there is a better pattern for the ***"fake_array"*** problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Imagining this was pure SQL, how would your query look? Or do you accept solutions where the query doesn't filter, but you filter in Python afterwards?

Comment: I'd expect this: MyModel.query.filter_by(fake_array="1").all() --> Select * From MyModel where fake_array = '1'

Comment: And event this: MyModel.query.filter(MyModel.fake_array.like('%1%')).all() --> Select * From MyModel where fake_array like '%1%'

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do should really be replaced with a pair of tables and a relationship between them.

The first table (which I'll call A) contains everything BUT the array column, and it should have a primary key of some sort. You should have another table (which I'll call B) that contains a primary key, a foreign key column to A (which I'll call a_id, and an integer field.

Using this layout, each row in the A table has its associated array in table B where B's a_id == A.id via a join. You can add or remove values from the array by manipulating the rows in table B. You can filter by using a join.

If the order of the values is needed, then create an order column in table B.

Comment: Sure! that'd be the best solution in a strict relational model. But sometimes I prefer this kind of tricks in my code rather than a ton of tables. Please, don't kill me for that ;).